# SQL count nulls and non nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

Apologies if there is already an answer out there for this, I couldn't find it anywhere!

I want to create a SQL query (in Oracle) displays a list of all A, B, C rows, example below, where there are more than 1 counts of D, including Nulls.

Say I have 5 columns:

```
A   B   C     D    E 
1   1   100   A    1 
1   1   100        2 
1   1   200   A    3 
1   1   200        1 
2   2   100   A    2 
2   2   100        3
2   2   100   B    1
2   2   100   C    2
```

The blanks are null.

I want the following results back, ignoring E altogether:

```
A   B   C     count 
1   1   100   2
1   1   200   2
2   2   100   4
```

The problem I have currently is that if I use the following query, it doesn't count the nulls:

```
SELECT A, B, C, count(D)
FROM <TABLE>
GROUP BY A, B, C HAVING COUNT(D) > 1
```

I know that count(*) does take into account nulls but I have other columns in my table that I don't want to include in my query.

Comment: Could you update the way the columns and results are displayed? I can't read it.

Comment: Hm, I get a total count of 8 so all rows are counted... do you mean that C could be null?

Comment: The result is what I want, not what i'm currently getting. 

Edit - that should be COUNT(D)

Comment: *"I know that `count(*)` does take into account nulls but I have other columns in my table that I don't want to include in my query"* - do you realise that `count(*)` doesn't check the value of every single column in the table; it's just a way of saying "count the rows (instead of specific values)" ?

Comment: Cheers Mark, I have just realised that now by looking at these answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple [`COUNT(*)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions032.htm#i82697)` should do it

```
SELECT A, B, C, COUNT(*) count
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY A, B, C
 ORDER BY A, B, C
```

Output:

```
| A | B |   C | COUNT |
-----------------------
| 1 | 1 | 100 |     2 |
| 1 | 1 | 200 |     2 |
| 2 | 2 | 100 |     4 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/786c4/2)** demo

`COUNT(*)` just counts the rows therefore it doesn't care for `NULL`s. On the other hand when you specify the column it will count only rows with non-null values in that column.

Comment: Thanks Peterm, with a "having count(*) > 1" and that also works for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a count, and be sure that it counts every row even if you have no column to count that is reliably not null, just use `SUM(1)` or `COUNT(*)`instead of count on the column;

```sql
SELECT A, B, C, SUM(1) dcount1, COUNT(*) dcount2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY A, B, C 
HAVING SUM(1) > 1
```

This counts every row, no matter if any column is NULL.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b756e/6).

Comment: sum(1) would be better as count(*), I think. The same result, but the sum is a little less orthodox.

Comment: Note Mark Bannister's comment on your misinterpretation of what count(*) does.

Comment: Yeah, I was incorrectly thinking about the way count(*) works when it's used solely by itself in a select statement to count ALL rows.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is given by:

```
SELECT A, B, C, count(*)
FROM <TABLE>
GROUP BY A, B, C
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If what you want is for the count to be based on distinct values in D, then:

```
SELECT A, B, C, count(distinct coalesce(d,'!'))
FROM <TABLE>
GROUP BY A, B, C
HAVING count(distinct coalesce(d,'!')) > 1
```

Choose a value as the second argument of coalesce() that is never present in the table -- preferably one that a constraint prevents from existing.